# How to take the result from another method

Tags: ruby

I have a directory structure with sub-directories:

```
../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_A/cats/
../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_B/dogs/
../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_A/tigers/
../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_A/elephants/
```

each of which has a file that ends with `".sln"`:

```
../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_A/cats/cats.sln
../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_B/dogs/dogs.sln
...
```

These files contain information specific to their directory. I would like to do the following:

1. Create a file `"myfile.txt"` within each sub-directory, and write some strings to them:

   ```
   ../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_A/cats/myfile.txt
   ../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_B/dogs/myfile.txt
   ../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_A/tigers/myfile.txt
   ../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_A/elephants/myfile.txt
   ```
2. Copy a specific string in the `".sln"` files to the `myfile.txt` of certain directories using the following method:

   ```
   def parse_sln_files
     sln_files = Dir["../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_*/**/*.sln"]
     sln_files.each do |file_name|
       File.open(file_name) do |f|
         f.each_line { |line|
           if line =~ /C Source files ="..\\/                                   #"
             path = line.scan(/".*.c"/)
             puts path
           end
         }
       end
     end
   end
   ```

I would like to do something like this:

```
def create_myfile
  Dir['../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_*/*/'].each do |dir|
    File.new File.join(dir, 'myfile.txt'), 'w+'
    Dir['../../../../../TEST/TEST_*/*/myfile.txt'].each do |path|
      File.open(path,'w+') do |f|
        f.puts "some text...."
        f.puts "some text..."
        f.puts # here I would like to return the result of parse_sln_files
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions on how to express this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to read list of C file names from a Visual C++ Solution file, and store in a separate file in the same directory.  You may have to merge the two loops that you have shown in your code, and do something like this:

```
def parse_sln_and_store_source_files
  sln_files = Dir["../../../../../MY_PROJECT/TEST_*/**/*.sln"]
  sln_files.each do |file_name|

    #### Lets collect source file names in this array
    source_file_names = []

    File.open(file_name) do |f|
      f.each_line { |line|
        if line =~ /C Source files ="..\\/                                  #"
          path = line.scan(/".*.c"/)

          ############ Add path to array ############
          source_file_names << path
        end
      }
    end

    #### lets create `myfile.txt` in same dir as that of .sln     
    test_file = File.expand_path(File.dirname(file_name)) + "/myfile.txt"

    File.open(test_file,'w+') do |f|
        f.puts "some text...."
        f.puts "some text..."

        ##### Iterate over source file names & write to file
        source_file_names.each { |n| f.puts n }
    end

  end
end
```

This can be done bit more elegantly with few more refactoring.  Also note that this is not tested code, hopefully, you get the gist of what I am suggesting.

Comment: Bravo! that's exactly I wanted!